# Writhing list to text file

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a simple list in a text file.

```
typedef int DATA;

struct lista {

    DATA info;
    struct lista *urm;
};

typedef struct lista Lista,*LISTA;

int main()
{
    int x;
    FILE *f;
    LISTA l;
    l=newl();
    l=(LISTA)malloc(sizeof(Lista));
    scanf("%d",&x);
    do{
         l=inserare_in_fata(l,x);
         scanf("%d",&x);
      } while(x!=0); // reading list elements until he read 0
    scrieFis(f,l);
}
LISTA newl()
{
    return NULL;
}

LISTA inserare_in_fata(LISTA l,DATA x)
{
    LISTA f;
    f=(LISTA)malloc(sizeof(Lista));
        f->info=x;
        f->urm=l;
        return f;
}

int scrieFis(FILE *f,LISTA l)
{
    f=fopen("date.txt","wt");
    if(f!=NULL)
    {
        while(l->urm!=NULL)
        {
            fprintf(f,"%d ",l->info);
            l=l->urm;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Nu s-a putut realiza scrierea fisierului!");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

In the text file, the writes the list, but also after a big pack of addresses*of pointers I think).
At the start I prepared through function newl() to have NULL and after making another points with information and paste before l in the list.

Comment: could you please include LISTA definition? I mean how is defined

Comment: Without the definition of LISTA is pretty much impossible to be said. I suppose info is an int (l->info). and example of the output would help as well.

Comment: Unrelated but the while loop will never handle the last item in the list. The loop will end when `l->urm == NULL`, meaning the current item is the last one in the list.

Comment: Could show us the example output text file?

Comment: http://uploadimage.ro/2FMd/Program_2.jpg

Comment: Are you sure `urm` is `NULL` for the last item in the list? Looks like the while loop just keeps on going beyond the end of the list.

Comment: Yeah, looks like the while loop is not stopping, but the code I think is good. I updated the question with the suplimentary information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You populate your list backwards,so the first item allocated becomes the last in the list. But the `urm` member for this item is never initialised with `NULL` indicating it is the last item.

In the main function:

```
l=(LISTA)malloc(sizeof(Lista));  //memory allocated for first (last when list is populated) item
l->urm = NULL;  //initialise urm to NULL, indicating this is the last item
scanf("%d",&x);
//etc...
```

This way the while loop can detect the last item in the list and stop.

Comment: Thanks for the response.Just a question! It's working, you say that I populate the list backwards, but the function did create a new pointer which is positioned before the pointer l and the new list become the created list (f) + l with NULL, did not?

Comment: Yes, so the list grows backwards. If you allocate 3 nodes for example the order becomes 3->2->1->NULL.

Comment: Ok, so if the list will be 3->2->1->NULL, why the while didn't read NULL(from the position 4).

Comment: Because `urm` was never set to `NULL` for item 1. `inserare_in_fata` makes the new item point to the previous one, but the first item, allocated in `main` never had it's  `urm` member set with a meaningfull value.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.